# Slick result set size default limit

Tags: scala, oracle11g, akka-stream, slick-3.0, alpakka

I wonder if there is a default resultset size when performing DBAction with slick akka-streaming integration.

Indeed (I am using akka-stream slick). When I write the following query:

```
Slick.source(sql"""select * FROM DRUG""".as[(Map[String,String])])
```

as in

```
val tableRows =
    Slick.source(sql"""select * FROM DRUG""".as[(Map[String,String])])
      .map{e => RawData("DRUG", "/Users/xxxx/xxxx/WSP1WS5-DRUG-auto-model.ttl", "OBJECT", "", e)}
      .mapAsyncUnordered(8){value =>
        Future{
          println(s"Writing {${value.toString}}")
          val kryo = kryoPool.obtain()
          val outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
          val output = new Output(outStream, 4096)
          kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, value)
          output.close()
          kryoPool.free(kryo)
          new ProducerRecord[String, Array[Byte]]("test", outStream.toByteArray)
        }
      }
      .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))
```

My query return up to something like 400 records and then just hang there. I have about 5k records in that table. Is that normal?

However I have been able to retrieve them all, albeit, I believe slower than it should be, by using the following statement:

> Slick.source(sql"""select * FROM DRUG Where ROWNUM <=
>   1000000000""".as[(Map[String,String])])

The database i am tapping on is oracle by the way. Hence i wonder if it is oracle, slick, or the akka-stream integration that cause this.

Any suggestion on this ?

Comment: Its certainly not `Oracle` since it already return few rows. That means oracle has worked and either slick or integration is not able to consume the data produced by `Oracle`

Comment: I'm guessing maybe your `producer` can be the one not requesting more data upstream, so, the source will not produce more messages. Try to use a simple sink just to know if the issue is not from `Oracle`: `source.runWith(Sink.foreach(println))`